# How to access database using DB2 10.5

Tags: db2

Does anyone knows how to access database using DB2 10.5 version. i heard that we have to open GUI using command prompt. not sure how to access.

Previously I had V9.5 now that version has been deprecated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by accessing the database, can you describe what you did in 9.5 and why that is not working with 10.5?

Answer (score 0):

IBM discontinued the DB2 Control Center GUI tool in favor of IBM Data Studio, an IDE based on Eclipse. Data Studio is not bundled with DB2 the way Control Center was, but it is available as a free download from IBM.

Answer (score -1):

To connect to a db2 database you can use:

```
db2 connect to $DB
```

Changing `$DB` to your database